# How to dispose of Autofac container?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I have a static class to setup Autofac registration and its method is called in Application_Start. Something like this:

```
public static class RegisterAutofac
{
    public static void Setup()
    {
        var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        //Do registration here...

        var container = builder.Build();
        var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
    }
}
```

So far I haven't found examples that dispose the container.

Is this enough or should I return the container and then dispose of the container in Dispose method in Global.asax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you do not need to call it as the `AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver` is already IDisposable and receives the container as a dependency. It is calling the Dispose when you dispose the `AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver`

The AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver will be disposed automatically by the system as the HttpConfiguration object inside Configuration already disposes it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: No. Should I return the resolver from this method and dispose it in global.asax?

Comment: I believe the question is asking how and if it makes sense to dispose the _container_ itself